# Is it possible to select a default community when the root *.force.com domain is accessed (without the community URL prefix)?

Tags: community, force.com-sites

Currently, my production org behaves this way:

1. `https://org1.force.com` responds with `503`, displaying a visualforce-based in-maintenance error page saying, "*https://org1.force.com/community is down for maintenance*"
2. `http://org1.force.com` responds with `307` to `https://org1.force.com` which then responds with `503`; ie., same outcome as #1
3. `https://org1.force.com/community` responds with a `301` to
   `https://org1.force.com/community/s/` where `/community` loads properly.

Is it possible to configure my org such that the root force.com domain defaults to one of many communities on the org?

Also, why doesn't scenario #1 redirect like scenario #3 even though the VF error page is already referencing it anyway?

Comment: It would work if the community does not have a path defined and lives at root of the domain. Does you community have a path name after root URL?

Comment: This is possible out of the box if you implement a [custom domain](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=domain_mgmt_domain_config_options.htm&type=5)  - it is the right way to go about any of the URL business in sites/communities

Comment: @manjit5190 I suppose it works if the URL prefix is removed on the community that we wish to default. Though I feel it's not the most ideal as it affects bookmarks and potentially break code/email templates that aren't properly using community variables.

Comment: @identigral Not sure how having a site domain helps. Could you elaborate? In the above example, `org1` is the (sample) site domain.

Comment: Custom domain will do a proper redirect from root (http(s)://foo.customdomain.com/) to the community URL for both http and https